# How can I get a context in classes I'm testing using JUnit?

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm writing JUnit tests for some of my methods. One of these methods accesses a string resource using `App.getContext().getString(...)`, but `App.getContext()` is `null` when running my JUnit test. I have looked into [InstrumentationRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) (which replaces the deprecated `AndroidTestCase`), but this just gives me a context I can use inside of my test. I need to be able to use a context in the method I'm calling. I would rather not have to add a parameter to the method to pass in context just for this test.

**Is there an easy way that I can fake a context in my test or another way to access the string resource?**

Comment: Unfortunately injecting Context in to classes is quite common. Another method is to instead pull the String out of the Context then inject the String in to the class.  That way you don't even need a Context at all to test the component.

Comment: Yeah I think I am just going to go with putting the string as a constant in the class instead of a resource for now. There doesn't seem to be a nicer option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this with AndroidX

```
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        val appContext = androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        val textView = TextView(appContext)
        textView.text = "sample"
        assertEquals("sample", textView.text) // PASS
        assertEquals("com.my.pk", appContext.packageName) // Will Fail, got com.my.pk.test
    }
```

The original template provides by AndroidStudio

```
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        assertEquals("com.style.me.styleme", appContext.packageName)
    }
```

is deprecated, but still available (2019)

Answer (score 0):

Android context just for unit test can be accessed using Robielectric tets framework.